# Local symbols in ELF's DYNSYM section are not actually local? How to tell?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, elf, dlopen

I'm trying to implement symbol resolution for my [check-link-consistency](https://github.com/dimgel/check-link-consistency) tool (analog of Gentoo's `revdep-rebuild`, but for Arch).

There are no symbols with `bind=STB_LOCAL` on my system (desktop Artix), but about 12% (381522) with `versym=VER_NDX_LOCAL`; the most of them (379189) are in `section=SHN_UNDEF`.

Most of these "local undefined" symbols -- but not all! -- are actually resolved by other libraries. Common pattern is that local symbols in `/usr/lib/xxx/.../*.so` actually reference global symbols in `/usr/lib/xxx.so` (and in its NEEDED libraries, and sometimes in other dynamically loaded libraries). I assume these `/usr/lib/xxx/.../*.so` are loaded dynamically using `dlopen()` by `/usr/lib/xxx.so` as plugins.

To ensure there are no orphan symbols on the system, I can specify that `/usr/lib/xxx.so` is NEEDED lib for all `/usr/lib/xxx/.../*.so` via my tool's config file:

```
addLib=/usr/lib/bash/** /usr/bin/bash
addLib=/usr/lib/hwloc/** /usr/lib/libhwloc.so
...
addLib=/usr/lib/xorg/modules/** /usr/lib/Xorg
```

(`**` means "including subdirectories", i.e. last line applies to `modules/drivers` too.) Currenly my config has 60 such lines.

**The problem** is that 50 such "local undefined" symbols don't reference anything (I cannot find corresponding exported symbol on the system), yet they are in `section=SHN_UNDEF` and they don't differ from "resolvable" local symbols in any other way I was able to check. Most of them are in nVidia blob `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so`:

- e.g. most of `mi*` symbols are resolved to `/usr/lib/Xorg` (e.g. `miPolyRectangle`);
- but some are orphan (e.g. `miRegionCreate`).

I was told these orphan symbols are long removed from X11 lib and now are inline, but how can I tell them from those I should resolve? **How loader distinguishes them?** Or if it does not, meaning it just silently ignores "local undefined" symbols it could not resolve (which is totally weird), then I should too -- thus leaving 12% of symbols on the system unchecked (and ending up with much smaller config file, speaking of the bright side). And might be practically irrelevant, but for better understanding: why these inline symbols are in DYNSYM section at all?

Thanks for reading thus far. :)